# Why setting max_connections to a high value in MySQL is considered bad?

Tags: mysql

Trying to understand. If I configure MySQL with a high max_connections and large buffers for each client it will handle the situation when there're not many connections but big requests and when there're a lot of clients with small requests.

How lowering down buffers and/or max clients is better?

Comment: It makes it easier to overload the server, because it will allow more connections than it's able to handle reasonably.

Answer (score 0):

That question would probably be more appropriate for serverfault.com or dba.stackexchange.com.

However, it all depends on what you consider "high value". If you've got a beefy server and a need for many simultaneous  connections, set it as high as you need, as long as it doesn't slow you down.

Keep in mind that the default configuration was intended for servers with 512 MB RAM - if you have, say, 512 GB, you can certainly safely exceed it. There are some per-connection buffers (see read_buffer_size and sort_buffer_size options, for example) but they are relatively tiny. The large and important ones are the query cache and InnoDB buffer pool but they're shared between all connections.

In the end, the answer is "it depends." Tune it according to your hardware and according to your needs, and if there's no other way, buy a couple more sticks of RAM, or allocate more RAM for your VM.